# Alignment of TikZ object

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, floats, classicthesis

I'm using the classic thesis style by André Miede. As I have to import a lot of Matlab plots, I'm using [`matlab2tikz`](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022).

In the LaTeX document, I want the TikZ object to act like a normal `jpg`/`png` included by `\includegraphicx`.

When I include the TikZ object with

```
\begin{figure} 
\input{thetikzfile.tex} % <thetikzfile> contains \begin{tikz} etc.
\end{figure}
```

it is not properly aligned to the text, which would be the case if I had inserted a `jpg` with the command `\includegraphicx`

[image]

I tried to align the TikZ object using `\centering`; however, I still get the same result.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If I am correct in assuming that your thetikzfile.tex file consists only of your `tikzpicture` environment, `\include` is not the appropriate command to use here; try `\input` instead. See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).

Comment: Have you tried `input` instead of `include`? I use the former all the time and it works perfectly.

Comment: I've edited the code. I did actually use `\input`.

Comment: Can you describe how it is mis-aligned? Not centered? Have you tried to use a bounding box in your TikZ code?

Comment: @KevinC I've uploaded an example on imgur.[link](http://imgur.com/Lw0FWH3) 

I haven't modified the tikzpicture, which I got from the matlab2tikz function, at all. I'll have a try when I'm back at home.

Comment: @Matthaeus: It seems like an issue with `classicthesis`. I have no problem getting the correct alignment if the `classicthesis` package is not used. This post might be relevant [Figures and margins in classicthesis](http://16marzo.blogspot.ca/2009/09/figure-e-margini-in-classicthesis.html). Some preliminary trial on my part has not been successful, however.

Comment: I've found the error:
I scaled the the tikzpicture by setting the axis to `\textwidth`, whereas I should have scaled the tikzpicture to `\textwidth`